# Assigning values from a .dat to an array in C

Tags: c, arrays

This might be a simple question but it's one I have to ask because I haven't learned it. I'm not sure how to assign elements to an array when these elements come from an outside file. Whiiich might sound kind of confusing it basically goes like this:

I have 2 files (well 3 but once I learn how to deal with this I can apply the same to the other file), gn1.c and scores.dat.

In gn1.c,
I have a 2D array, that is defined like this:

```
int scores[13][4];
```

It isn't initialized to anything. I would like to assign each element of this array a specific integer that is stored in another file 'scores.dat'.

scores.dat, in it's entirety, looks like this:

```
88 77 85 91 65 72 84 96 50 76 67 89 70 80 90 99 42 65 66 72 80 82 85 83 90 89 93 
98 86 76 85 99 99 99 99 99 84 72 60 66 50 31 20 10 90 95 91 10 99 91 85 80
```

So, essentially, I would like scores[0][0] to be 88, and scores [0][1] to be 77 and etc;

The values would be stored so that if, later on in the program, I referenced it like this:

```
if(scores[12][3] < 90)
a_ct++;
```

scores[12][3] would be read as 80.

So is there a specific syntax for what I'm trying to do or am I misunderstanding some kind of basic?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to read the file with functions like fopen, fread, and fclose - they are all defined in stdio.h.

You will first have to open the file like this:

```
FILE * fp = fopen( "scores.dat", "r" ); // "r" means read.
```

Then you would read the file with fread, sort of like this:

```
char number[ 2 ];
fread( fp, 1, 2, number );
```

Then you would convert that number to an integer, with atoi (asci to integer )

```
scores[ 0 ][ 0 ] = atoi( number );
```

And you would do this in a loop until you've read all your values. When your done, you 
close the file.

```
fclose( fp );
```

Here's some links to check out for more information:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/?kw=fopen

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/?kw=fread

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fclose/

You might need to reference these to check the functions for errors ( which I haven't done in the code above just for clarity ). And if your are interested in c++ as well, the functions in it's standard library make it very simple as well.

Comment: Is file * fp = fopen defined within the local variables or is that part of the loop? Or is the only thing in the loop itself the scores[0][0] = atop( number );?

Comment: fread and atoi would both be in the loop. and the fopen and fclose would be outside of the loop.